# Putting package documentation on Wolfram Cloud

Tags: packages, wolfram-cloud

So, I've finally released v1.0 of my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo).  Yay.  Maybe I'll give an overview here soon.

I'd also like to advertise to my colleagues, perhaps non-Mathematica users, who might use it.  The documentation, made with Workbench, has some worked examples already, so I thought it might be easiest to publish them on the Wolfram Cloud.  I opened one such tutorial in the Mathematica help browser and hit "Publish to Cloud...", and it [doesn't look too bad](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/Published/Trait-Based%20Lotka-Volterra%20Competition)!

However, it doesn't look perfect either:
[image]

The search bar was included and is totally non-functional.  The links under "Related Tutorials" at the top and bottom don't work.

Still, this seems 95% of the way towards having decent-looking documentation on the web without much trouble.

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to remove that broken search-bar header and fix the links?
2. Can I upload all the documentation pages to the cloud automatically, and maintain the directory structure?

Comment: `paclet:` to properly linked can be resolved by using `URLParse` on them then changing the `"Scheme"` and `"Domain"` via `ReplacePart` and if needed also inserting the path before hitting it with a `URLBuild` or whatever the functions are again. This assumes you already know where the stuff will be going. Otherwise you'll need relative linking _inside_ the package and to full WRI docs outside. I took that approach at one time before I decided I didn't want to host documentation for my packages (or really deal with documentation in any way...).

Comment: I updated my answer to address the problem with `paclet:` links. It's in the same spirit as the (slightly later) suggestion by @b3m2a1 above. Could certainly be made a bit more sophisticated, but should be a good start. Does this help, @Chris K?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Good to hear it (almost) works!

1. The header is a docked cell, so, to remove it, you could evaluate

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], DockedCells->{}]
```

in the notebook (before you publish it to the cloud).

2. To upload a whole directory to the cloud, you can use

```
CopyDirectory["localpath", CloudObject["cloudpath"]]
```

(with `localpath` and `cloudpath` set appropriately). To make all the created cloud objects public, you could temporarily change `$Permissions`, or you could (recursively) iterate over them using `CloudObjects` and apply `SetPermissions` to each of them. We're working on more direct ways to do this, also in the GUI ("Publish Directory to Cloud"). Documentation also needs to be further improved, but the guide page about [Managing Content in the Cloud](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ManagingContentInTheCloud.html) is a good starting point for more information.

To address the problem with `paclet:` hyperlinks: I think the best option (for now) is to preprocess each notebook before publishing it to the cloud, replacing the target URLs of all such `ButtonBox`es with corresponding cloud object URLs. Here's some code that does this:

```
dirPrefixes = <|
   "Guides" -> "guide", {"ReferencePages", "Symbols"} -> "ref", 
   "Tutorials" -> "tutorial"|>;

subdirString[prefix_String] := prefix
subdirString[prefixes_List] := FileNameJoin[prefixes]

pacletLinkQ[str_String] := StringStartsQ[str, "paclet:"]
pacletLinkQ[_] := False

fixPacletLink[str_, pacletName_, targetURL_] := 
 StringReplace[
   str, (StartOfString ~~ "paclet:" ~~ pacletName) -> targetURL] <> 
  ".nb"

fixPacletLinks[nb_Notebook, pacletName_, targetDir_String] := 
 nb /. ButtonBox[content_, opts1___, ButtonData -> data_?pacletLinkQ, 
    opts2___] :> 
   ButtonBox[content, 
    ButtonFunction :> (FrontEndExecute[
        NotebookLocate[{URL[#2], None}]] &), opts1, 
    ButtonData -> fixPacletLink[data, pacletName, targetDir], opts2]

removeDockedCells[
  Notebook[content_, opts1___, DockedCells -> _, opts2___]] := 
 Notebook[content, opts1, DockedCells -> {}, opts2]
removeDockedCells[Notebook[content_, opts___]] := 
 Notebook[content, DockedCells -> {}, opts]

resetMagnification[
  Notebook[content_, opts1___, (Rule | RuleDelayed)[Magnification, _],
    opts2___]] := Notebook[content, opts1, opts2]
resetMagnification[nb_Notebook] := nb

fixStyleSheet[
  Notebook[content_, opts1___, StyleDefinitions -> _, opts2___]] := 
 Notebook[content, opts1, 
  StyleDefinitions -> FrontEnd`FileName[{"Wolfram"}, "Reference.nb"], 
  opts2]

publishDocNB[filename_String, target : CloudObject[targetURL_, ___], 
  prefix_, pacletName_] := 
 Module[{nb, newNB, obj}, nb = Get[filename]; 
  newNB = resetMagnification@
    fixStyleSheet@
     removeDockedCells@fixPacletLinks[nb, pacletName, targetURL]; 
  obj = FileNameJoin[{target, prefix, FileNameTake[filename]}]; 
  Print["Publishing ", filename, " to ", obj]; 
  CloudPublish[newNB, obj]]

publishDocDir[pacletDir_, subdir_, prefix_, target_] := 
 Module[{nbfiles = 
    FileNames["*.nb", 
     FileNameJoin[{pacletDir, "Documentation", "English", 
       subdirString[subdir]}]], pacletName = FileNameTake[pacletDir]},
   publishDocNB[#, target, prefix, pacletName] & /@ nbfiles]

PublishPacletDocs[pacletDir_String, target_CloudObject] := 
 KeyValueMap[publishDocDir[pacletDir, #1, #2, target] &, dirPrefixes]
```

Calling the function like

```
PublishPacletDocs["~/Projects/EcoEvo/EcoEvo", CloudObject["EcoEvo"]]
```

will publish all documentation notebooks in the given paclet directory (assuming they're all in the usual subdirectory structure of `Documentation/English`) to a cloud directory `EcoEvo` in your cloud home directory.

This also takes care of points 1 and 2, and, as a little bonus, I also made it change the stylesheet to `Wolfram/Reference.nb` (since `Wolfram/FunctionPageStyles.nb` doesn't exist right now) and reset the `Magnification` to 1. (You could also deploy a custom stylesheet to the cloud and reference that.)

You can see the result here: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/jpoeschko/EcoEvo/guide/EcoEvo.nb

(Hope it's okay that I took your https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo and published it to my own Wolfram Cloud account for now. Just let me know if I should replace the link in this answer with a link to your own published version.)

Comment: I was experimenting with this too recently, and while the docked cell would be easy to fix, there are many other rendering problems which would be just too much trouble for me to work around. On this page, https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/szhorvat/Published/MaTeX  open the Applications heading and see many pink boxes. I was not even able to reproduce these pink boxes if I copied those cells into a new notebook and uploaded that one to the cloud. In the end, I gave up on trying to fix it.

Comment: Trying to share docs like this seems like a lot of work. One would also need to rewrite the links (which now use the `paclet:...` format).

Comment: However, I do have a package whose documentation is a single notebook (for better or worse). I seriously considered sharing this through the cloud. See here: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/szhorvat/Published/IGDocumentation  Some issues with this: 1. ***Very*** slow rendering. This is somewhat understandable because the notebook is huge. But at the time when I originally uploaded it, the rendering was *not* this slow. Now it takes multiple minutes.

Comment: 2. WholeCellGroupOpener setting was either not honoured or went missing during cloud publishing ... This is better now because it seems that there are inline openers.  3. [There are some random pink boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWWbG.png) which will work the next time I load the page. The good news is that I have not yet found anything that is consistently pink in this notebook.

Comment: Generally, for documentation sharing purposes, it would be extremely useful if we could have a way to share strictly read-only, non-interactive notebooks that load fast and don't put a lot of strain on the browser (think e.g. reading them on a Raspberry Pi). It'd be sufficient to have input cells copyable, just like in Mathematica's online documentation.

Comment: A few more notes: The MaTeX doc notebooks were last saved with v10.0.2 (for compatibility), and created with several different versions (MaTeX is several years old). || In "IGDocumentation.nb", when I rotate 3D `Graph`s interactively, only the vertices are visible. || Most `Graph`s render in "retina resolution" temporarily when loading, then suddenly they drop to standard resolution. These are not dealbreakers for IGDocumntation, though.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for your update, which solves most of my problems.  I ran your script on the Workbench-built version of my docs, which looks even better.  (I've now exposed the "build" directory on github).  I had to add one more pattern to `fixPacletLinks`, namely `TemplateBox[{content_, data_?pacletLinkQ}, "RefLink", opts___] :> TemplateBox[{content, fixPacletLink[data, pacletName, targetDir]}, "WebLink", opts]`. Results are [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/EcoEvo/guide/EcoEvo.nb).

Comment: I've got only a few remaining issues.  The only crucial one is that closed cell groups don't have openers (especially bad for "Details" section).  Other less essential ones: the pulldown menus "See Also" and "Related Guides" on the top don't function and links to built-in Mathematica functions ask to "open in Mathematica" instead of linking to the web docs.  See [this page](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/EcoEvo/ref/SolveEcoEq.nb) for examples of these issues.  But this is quickly approaching great -- thanks!

Comment: TBH, I don't fully understand the problem yet and there's probably a bug with `WholeCellGroupOpener` that we need to fix, and maybe another problem that prevents the new-style group openers (on the right of the cell content). But I looked at the style definitions in `Reference.nb` and `ShowGroupOpener` is set depending on the notebook's `TaggingRules`. One way to make the traditional group openers (on the left) show up is to set the notebook option `TaggingRules->{"NewStyles"->False}`. I tried this (using `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ...]`) in a copy of your SolveEcoEq.nb and it's fine.

Comment: In terms of the pulldown menus at the top, you'd have to adjust the function `fixPacletLinks` to also look for these `ActionMenuBox`es and fix up their right-hand sides which involve ```Documentation`HelpLookup``` (or just replace all of those in the whole notebook expression).

Comment: @JanPöschko Omitting the `fixStyleSheet` step also brought the openers back, so something about those StyleSheets.  I should be able to figure out the pulldown menus myself.  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: Great! Thanks for the bounty. :-) Happy to help if you have follow-up questions.

Comment: @JanPöschko I ended up using `removePulldownMenus[Notebook[content_,opts___]]:=Notebook[content[[2;;]],opts];` to simply remove the pulldown menus.  The final product is [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/guide/EcoEvo.nb).  This should tide me over until the official paclet sharing becomes available.