# Wolfram Cloud slowdown

Tags: wolfram-cloud

Has anyone noticed a slowdown on Wolfram Cloud rendering? With [@JanPöschko's help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/207632/6358) I've been using Wolfram Cloud to share docs for my [EcoEvo package](https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo).
I just updated them and noticed that it takes a long time to render now.

The [main Guide page](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/guide/EcoEvo.nb) takes 1 second to load, but 1 minute and 40 seconds to make all the links active (watch the tiny blue progress bar under the "Wolfram Notebook" header).  Before the page has rendered, clicking on a link brings a popup saying "Starting interactivity..."
After it is done, clicking on a link is unresponsive for 25 seconds before going to the linked page.

I don't remember it being so slow before.  Has something changed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure yet what exactly changed – maybe the underlying "Reference.nb" stylesheet or our handling of `N` or `Inherited` (see below). We don't officially support documentation notebooks in the cloud yet (so we don't actively test that stylesheet), but, of course, this should "just work". So it's a little embarrassing this got slower. Sorry.

In cases like this, it can be very useful to look at our (rather experimental and un-polished) "devtools", e.g. by opening the page with an extra `?devtools=true` parameter: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/guide/EcoEvo.nb?devtools=true

This shows you all the kernel evaluations being made, which is usually the bottleneck (due to the round-trip time to the server). You can see a lot of evaluations with an evaluated `value` like

```
{CloudSystem`SynchronousEvaluate[
  "4cafbfd0-ee6b-428d-afe1-2b4635dd199c", 
  CloudSystem`UpdateDynamic[
   CloudSystem`Signing`SignedExpression[
    If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 
     RGBColor[0.054902`, 0.243137`, 0.72549`], Inherited], 
    "res:StyleSheets:Wolfram/Reference.nb"], None, N, 87236023836699, 
   6, 1585260120.881`]]}
```

– so what's happening is that it (unfortunately) uses the kernel to resolve essentially

```
If[CurrentValue["MouseOver"], 
 RGBColor[0.054902`, 0.243137`, 0.72549`], Inherited]
```

This should really be handled by the client-side evaluator, but it isn't (anymore?), I think because it doesn't know how to resolve `N[Inherited]`. We will try to get that fixed in Cloud 1.55.

In the meanwhile, you could avoid this by just not using a hover effect for hyperlinks, e.g. adding a style override like the following to your (inline) stylesheet:

```
Cell[StyleData["WebLink"], 
 TemplateBoxOptions -> {DisplayFunction :> (TagBox[
       ButtonBox[
        StyleBox[#, 
         FontColor -> RGBColor[0.054902, 0.243137, 0.72549]], 
        ButtonData -> {URL[#2], None}], 
       MouseAppearanceTag["LinkHand"]] &)}]
```

I have tried this, and it loads much faster: https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/jpoeschko/Published/EcoEvo-optimized.nb

It *might* also work to just replace `Inherited` with an explicit `RGBColor`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer.  I'll give it a try tonight!

Comment: @Jan Pöschko: Thank's for mentioning `?devtools=true`! Is there a place where more possible parameters are documented? Like the `?_view=frameless` parameter (e.g., in `CloudDeploy[Manipulate[Plot[Sin[x (1 + a x)], {x, 0, 6}], {a, 0, 2}],"test?_view=frameless",Permissions->"Public"]`) should also be documented. And, what is the parameter now to get more synchronous dynamic updating when e.g. moving a slider (?_view=frameless triggered that in older W(E)PC versions, but does not anymore).

Comment: I just added your `DisplayFunction` incantation to the code that fixes links before uploading to the cloud -- works perfectly.  Thanks again!

Comment: @RolfMertig `?devtools=true` is the only (semi-supported) extra parameter for notebooks I can think of right now. We are working on more documentation that would mention this. `?_view=frameless` is *not* officially supported and will be removed eventually; the cloud object option `AppearanceElements->None` should be used instead, moving forward. Other "views" are as exposed as `CloudObjectURLType` (more to come). The way to get immediate updates during interactions (even in the "Object" view) is to explicitly set `ContinuousAction->True` (e.g. in `Manipulate`).