# Tutorial notebook on GitHub

Tags: packages, development

I am currently writing a Mathematica package containing several functions I developed in the last few years to perform computations in quantum physics. I am planning to put a preliminary version of the code on GitHub very soon, such that people who are potentially interested in can give me feedbacks and so on.

To make the package easier to handle, I am also writing a notebook which can be used as a tutorial to learn the various functions of the package.

Is there a way to improve the way GitHub format the notebook? Something like the results you can get when you upload a Jupyter notebook. As far as I can understand, GitHub converts the Mathematica files into raw code: this is of course fine for the package, but it's not good for the notebook.

Comment: In short, no. Please search this site. The topic has been discussed quite a few times before. Consider http://packagedata.net/ instead.

Comment: Take a look at [[136634)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/136634/27951) and [(26174)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26174/what-are-the-recommended-settings-for-git-when-using-with-mathematica-projects/26180#26180).

Comment: Thank you, @MarcoB. I tried to ask again to check if something new came out more recently.

Comment: As an alternative to putting your tutorial on GitHub, you could put it on Wolfram Cloud.  See Q&A about exporting Workbench-made docs [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206705/putting-package-documentation-on-wolfram-cloud) and example [here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/EcoEvo/docs/guide/EcoEvo.nb).

Comment: Thank you, @ChrisK. I will! jus the time to put it in a more or less readable form!

Comment: https://github.com/cklausme/EcoEvo/blob/master/finish%20paclet.wl has various hacks I put together with help from folks around here for finishing a paclet after building the docs with Workbench.  You might find it useful.